# python unittest lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, python-unittest, marshmallow

I have unittest for api use [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in flask 1.1.2 and python 3.8 as bellow

*schema.py*

```
class ListSchema(Schema):
   id = fields.Integer()
   name = fields.String()
   gone_date = fields.Function(lambda data: data.gone_date.timestamp())
```

*main_service.py*

```
class MainService:
   @classmethod:
   def get_list(cls):
      list_schema = ListSchema()
      list_data, total = Class.function_get_list_data
      list_data = list_schema.dump(list_data, many=True)
```

When i run pytest for function `get_list`

```
mock = [(1, 'Name_1', datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 0, 0))], 10
mock_data = mock.Mock(return_value=mock)
with mock.patch.object(Class, 'function_get_list_data', mock_data):
   response = MainService.get_list()
```

I alway get error add lambda function in schema

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'gone_date'

How to pass or test via function lambda in this case. I have try catch with `raise unittest.skip` but it not my expectation. My function **still work normally**, only error when apply unittest. Thanks for help.

**Edit:**

This trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 60, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 676, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 633, in _callTestMethod
    method()
  File "/opt/project/app/test/service/test_main_service.py", line 79, in test_process_list
    response = MainService.get_list()
  File "/opt/project/app/main/service/main_service.py", line 18, in process_main_list
    list_data = list_schema.dump(list_data, many=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 557, in dump
    result = self._serialize(processed_obj, many=many)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 515, in _serialize
    return [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 516, in <listcomp>
    self._serialize(d, many=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 521, in _serialize
    value = field_obj.serialize(attr_name, obj, accessor=self.get_attribute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py", line 312, in serialize
    return self._serialize(value, attr, obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py", line 1722, in _serialize
    return self._call_or_raise(self.serialize_func, obj, attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py", line 1736, in _call_or_raise
    return func(value)
  File "/opt/project/app/main/schemas/schema.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    gone_date = fields.Function(lambda data: data.gone_date.timestamp())
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: From what you have listed here, you are passing a tuple into the lambda rather than a type which has an attribute called `gone_date`

Comment: @KlausD. I had add trace back.

Comment: @puffin. but my function still work normal. Only error when i write unittest

Comment: @dleviathan Then my guess would be that you are passing it a type it isn't expecting in the test method

Comment: @puffin maybe for mock data `mock = [(1, 'Name_1', datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 0, 0))]` is tuple. thanks